# Add/remove row to protected Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, triggers, rows, protected

First time asking questions. Generally I can get the responses/codes I neeed here (very helpful btw!) but now it got too complicated for me...

I have a script to add/remove rows. I can run it fine. However, the sheet I have is shared with other users and protected. I am the owner and wish to allow users to add/remove rows. They are editors. The protection does not allow them to run my code.

Studied installable triggers and gave it a try. No luck, as I am not very familiar with onChange/onEdit stuff.

Is there anyone who could shed some light? Any guidance is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you share a spreadsheet with  us please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would a simple spreadsheet suffice? I cant share the one I mention, as it is linked to my work profile. The issue I have is with the protection. How to run a script to add row using installable trigger?

Comment: yes only a spreadsheet with the problem suffice

Comment: Thanks - will get back with this shortly